# How to remove duplicates separated by a comma inside cells in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I was handled a very long excel file (up to 11000 rows and 7 columns) that has many repeated data inside a cell. I am looking for a macro to get rid of it but couldn't find any.

Example of one such cells:

Ciencias de la Educación,Educación,Pedagogía,Ciencias de la Educación,Educación,Pedagogía

It should look like:

Ciencias de la Educación,Educación,Pedagogía

How can I get rid of the thousands of repeats (not to mention the extra, orphaned, commas)?

Comment: [Check out](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261) Text to Columns. It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: No, not really. I'm looking for a way to get rid of about tens of thousands of repeated strings of text, what you suggested won't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code runs 6 seconds on my machine and 2 seconds on @SiddharthRout's machine:)** 
(with data in cells `A1:G20000` : 20000x7=140000 non empty cells)

```
Sub test2()
    Dim c, arr, el, data, it
    Dim start As Date
    Dim targetRange As Range

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set targetRange = Range("A1:G20000")

    data = targetRange

    start = Now
    For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
        For j = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
            c = data(i, j)
            dict.RemoveAll
            arr = Split(c, ",")
            For Each el In arr
                On Error Resume Next
                dict.Add Trim(el), Trim(el)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next
            c = ""
            For Each it In dict.Items
               c = c & it & ","
            Next
            If c <> "" Then c = Left(c, Len(c) - 1)
            data(i, j) = c
        Next j
    Next i
    targetRange = data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Working time: " & Format(Now - start, "hh:nn:ss")

End Sub
```

---

**You can make this code slightly faster** by changing next two lines

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
```

to

```
Dim dict As new Dictionary
```

after adding reference to library: go to *Tools->References* and select *"Microsoft Scripting Runtime"*

[image]

Comment: + 1 :) It took 8 seconds on my machine :)

Comment: BTW my method took 2 secs on A1:G20000 :P

Comment: I'm going to check it on my machine:)

Comment: OK. Don't write `sString` to the cell directly. Replace the value back in `MyAr(i)` and then write to the excel range right at the end (outside the loop) :)

Comment: your code runs for 13 seconds on my machine:) I'm going to try your last comment:)

Comment: 8 seconds with writing back in array:) I should check my code with this approach:)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, you code 8 sec, my code 6 sec with writing back on array:) I've updated answer with this approach:)

Comment: Not sure why are you getting 8 seconds ;) See my updated post in few secods. I am getting it done in 2 seconds...

Comment: Your code evaluates for 4 second:) main conclusion: my laptop is very slow:)))

Comment: 4 seconds vs your 6 seconds... Not bad :P

Comment: :P have you used earlier binding in my code: `Dim dict As new Dictionary`?

Comment: Yup I used Latebinding. Just changed it to Early Binding and your code now took 2 seconds. So both are methods finally take 2 seconds! Congrats :) It has been a good exercise. :D

Comment: But remember one thing, your code may give a different timing on the OP's PC since you are binding with `scrrun.dll` whereas my code doesn't...

Comment: @SiddharthRout, sorry for disturbing you again, just curious, check my last updat, what was the timing on your machine?) (don't forget to use `Dim dict As new Dictionary`) new version runs for me 4 sec, prev version - 6 sec:)

Comment: 2 seconds. @user3263960: For curiosity purpose, could you check how much time does my code take on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sString As String
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    Dim Col As New Collection
    Dim itm

    sString = "Ciencias de la Educación,Educación,Pedagogía,Ciencias de la Educación,Educación,Pedagogía"

    MyAr = Split(sString, ",")

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        On Error Resume Next
        Col.Add Trim(MyAr(i)), CStr(Trim(MyAr(i)))
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i

    sString = ""

    For Each itm In Col
        sString = sString & "," & itm
    Next

    sString = Mid(sString, 2)

    Debug.Print sString
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Tried and tested in Excel 2010 with `A1:G20000` filled with `Ciencias de la Educación,Educación,Pedagogía,Ciencias de la Educación,Educación,Pedagogía`

**Time Taken**: 2 Seconds

**Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sString As String
    Dim MyAr As Variant, rngAr
    Dim Col As New Collection
    Dim itm
    Dim rng As Range

    Debug.Print "StartTime: " & Now

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G20000")
    rngAr = rng.Value

    For i = LBound(rngAr) To UBound(rngAr)
        For j = LBound(rngAr, 2) To UBound(rngAr, 2)
            MyAr = Split(rngAr(i, j), ",")

            For k = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
                On Error Resume Next
                Col.Add Trim(MyAr(k)), CStr(Trim(MyAr(k)))
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next k

            sString = ""

            For Each itm In Col
                sString = sString & "," & itm
            Next

            sString = Mid(sString, 2)

            rngAr(i, j) = sString
        Next j
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(20000, 7).Value = rngAr

    Debug.Print "EndTime: " & Now
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: I've little beat changed it..if change `If Not dict.Exists(Trim(el)) Then` to `OERN` code evaluates for 1 second faster:)