# Is there a function in Excel that removes duplicate strings from within a cell?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, vba

The UDF and other solutions offered in other questions do not solve this problem. Perhaps it is the length of the strings, and then number of duplicates in my problem. (All numbers, separated by commas, 13 digits long, 2 to 3 unique numbers repeated approximately 20-40 times in a single cell.)

I reviewed the answers to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897429/remove-duplicates-within-excel-cell) but those answers didn't work properly with my data.

Is there a function or a formula that I can use to remove duplicate strings within a single cell?

If,

A1=10,10,10,10,11,11,12,12,12 (the actual numbers are 13 digits each and they are either 2 or 3 unique numbers that repeat. I just need to capture each unique number)

Is there a simple way like RemoveDups() that will remove the duplicates and leave just . A1=10,11,12?  Or do I need to create a UDF?

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533574/how-to-remove-duplicates-separated-by-a-comma-inside-cells-in-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates within Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897429/remove-duplicates-within-excel-cell)

Answer (score 3):

```
Function RemoveDuplicates(v As Variant) As String
Dim aSplit As Variant, aUnique() As Variant, vMatch As Variant, a As Variant

aSplit = Split(v, ",")

ReDim Preserve aUnique(0 To x)
aUnique(0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept("|^|", 20)

For Each a In aSplit
    vMatch = Application.Match(Trim(a), aUnique, 0)

    If IsError(vMatch) Then
        x = x + 1
        ReDim Preserve aUnique(0 To x)
        aUnique(x) = Trim(a)
    End If
Next a

RemoveDuplicates = Join(Filter(aUnique, aUnique(0), False), ",")

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out on Monday when I get back to work.

Comment: It sort of works, it might be because the numbers I used for the example were 2 digits, but the actual spreadsheet I'm working on all of the numbers have 13 digits.

Comment: A1=1012024228160, 1012024228160, 1012024228160, 1012024228160, 1012024228162, 1012024228162, 1012024228162, 1012024228162   OUTPUT A2=1012024228160,,1012024228162,,1012024228162

Comment: If it takes care of your question then please mark this thread as solved.

Comment: It does not solve my question because the output includes duplicates and has duplicate commas as indicated in the comment. But it is almost there, are you able to correct the errors in the code?

Comment: Updated the answer post with my revised code.   Fixed the bug.

Comment: It is improved, it got rid of the duplicate commas, but it still duplicates the last number for some reason. SOURCE=10101010101, 10101010101, 10101010101, 20202020202, 20202020202, 20202020202, 20202020202, 3030303003, 303030303
OUTPUT=10101010101,20202020202,3030303003,303030303

Comment: Because in 3030303003 & 303030303 one zero is missing in the second one when comparing to the first one.  So it's working fine I think.

Comment: This is so weird. I thought I copied and pasted the 303030303 to do the test. I'll check again.